# How to pass two parameters in a linked list node using c?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am learning how to use structure with linked list in c. So I was trying to keep inserting the node to first position. Also, each node contains two different kinds of values, one is char array and another one is integer. Once I insert a value, then print the current list out. I look over and over again but I can't find where gets something wrong because I set a printf() test in the insert function. I saw the new_node is what I currently insert.

When I insert a 1 first and it prints out a/1. But I am so confusing when I insert another set such as b 2, it prints out

b/2

b/1

which means the name of first node changed along with inserting a new node, but the numbers did not change. Can anyone see what happened here?

```
struct node{
    char *name;
    int numbers;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *list = NULL;

void printList(struct node *node){
    while (node != NULL){
        printf("%s/%d\n", node->name, node->numbers);
        node = node->next;
  }
}

void insert(struct node **list, char *name, int numbers){
    struct node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->name = name;
    new_node->numbers = numbers;
    //printf("......%s %d.........\n", new_node->name, new_node->numbers);
    new_node->next = *list;
    *list = new_node;
}

int main(){
    ......code for scanf() are omitted......
    insert(&list, name, numbers);
    printList(list);
}
```

Comment: `new_node->name = name;` --> make copy like `new_node->name = strdup(name);`

Comment: And don't forget to free up your node in a correct way, means free the name pointer as it is an allocated memory that the only pointer to it is this node name.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why char array needs to be strdup but integer don't?

Comment: Because `name` is pointer(`numbers` is not pointer). That pointer point to same buffer.

Comment: Please include main() code that you have deleted

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I through if I keep refreshing the list then the current node is always the first one. The only thing I need is add the value into the current node. That is so strange the "saved" list also changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your are pointing on same buffer for every node.
Even without seeing the code you removed, I can guess you are reading the node names in same char array.
You would better consider using strdup() as it was suggested:

```
new_node->name = strdup(name);
```

Make sure you free this pointer when you are destroying the node.

Comment: You are right, this is where the problem is. But I don't understand if the 'name' is pointing to current name, why I can't just update the name of current node?

Comment: All your nodes will point on same buffer, means all of them will be with same name, effectually with the name of last node you've inserted.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings take the form of 'character arrays', that is - a series of char variables next to each other, followed by a null character.

When you see something like

```
char* string = "foo";
```

in C, that is the declaration of a `char*`, (a pointer to a variable of type `char`) assigned the memory address of the first character in a string. In your insert function the line

```
new_node->name = name;
```

takes the memory address assigned to `name` and stores it in your object. It does *not* store the string value itself in your object; that remains exactly where it was. If you then use `scanf()`, passing in the same pointer, you will overwrite the original string, which the object you previously created is *still* pointing to.

Comment: Make sense! Thank you all!